# Проблема с cx_freeze

Tags: python, компиляция, cx-freeze

Компилирую паука scrapy при помощи cx_Freeze. Файл setup.py находится на одном уровне с пауком. При компиляции в командой строке появляется сообщение о пропущеных модулях и они перечисляются.

После компиляции открываю полученный .exe и получаю ошибку, в конце которой написано:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zope'
```

Установил zope командой: `pip install zope`. Результат не изменился.

Что сделать, чтобы компиляция прошла успешно?

Код в setup.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

incl = ['csv',
        'scrapy',
        'scrapy.crawler',
        'scrapy.http',
        'scrapy.settings',
        ]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages': incl,
    }
}

setup(
    name='things',
    version='1.0',
    description='Parser shoes shop',
    options=options,
    executables=[Executable('program.py', base=base)]

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поискал вашу проблему и нашел: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/319

Согласно [примеру](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/blob/6.0b1/cx_Freeze/samples/zope/setup.py#L18), нужно так:

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'namespace_packages': ['zope']
    }
}
```

А в вашем случае:

```
incl = [
    'csv',
    'scrapy',
    'scrapy.crawler',
    'scrapy.http',
    'scrapy.settings',
]

options = {
    'build.exe': {
        'packages': incl,
        'namespace_packages': ['zope']
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. К сожалению, ни zope.intefrace, ни zope, при добавлении, не помогли

Comment: @Jumper, обновил ответ, проверьте, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка пропала и стали появляться другие(не видел модуль). Решил аналогичным способом, добавляя через запятую нужные модули.